# How can i display the delivery orders automatically in a way that the most recent is the first?

Tags: odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 and i want to display delivery orders in a way that the last one (the most recent) is the first to display automatically . I tried to apply a filter to do this order but there is no solution. The only solution that i found is to press on the field date to make it in order that the last delivery created is shows the first. Is there a solution to do that automatically espacially that the sale orders display in thist way? Any idea for help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inherit the `stock.picking` object and add the *"_order"* attribute(order by *create_date* **descending**)

```
_order = "create_date desc, priority desc, date asc, id desc"
```

This will show the recent created Delivery orders first

```
class Picking(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking"
    _description = "Transfer"
    _order = "create_date desc, priority desc, date asc, id desc"
```